# How to make dynamic source youtube url on dummy and show as a video

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube, dummy-variable, video-player

I don't know how to show a video as a dynamic source video url. This is my dummy

```
interface DummyMusicDataSource {
    fun getMusicData(context: Context): List<Music>
}

class DummyMusicDataSourceImpl() : DummyMusicDataSource {
    override fun getMusicData(context: Context): List<Music> {

        return mutableListOf(
            Music(
                title = "title",
                imgUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryhanhxx/img_asset/main/IMG_MATERI_3.jpg",
                desc = context.getString(R.string.desc_materi_1),
                videoUrl = "yTRdWD_ar78",
            )
        )
    }
}
```

This is my ViewHolder on my activity

```
    private fun showMusicData(music: Music?) {
        music?.apply {
            binding.ivImg.load(this.imgUrl) {
               crossfade(true)
            }
            binding.tvTitle.text = this.title
            binding.tvDesc.text = this.desc
            //TODO : binding id videoplayer and show as a video
        }
    }

    private fun playVideo(){
        val youTubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView = binding.youtubePlayerView
        lifecycle.addObserver(youTubePlayerView)

        youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                val videoId = "S0Q4gqBUs7c"
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0f)
            }
        })
```

And this is my xml

```
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:autoPlay="false"
                app:videoId="GYZpknfi5YQ" />
```

I wanna make "app:videoId" as a dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add `app:videoId="GYZpknfi5YQ"` in your XML.

There are multiple ways to make it dynamic. **I am assuming** that you are calling the `playVideo` method in the `onBindViewHolder` method. In that case, in the `onBindViewHolder()` method, you can call `playVideo` method with the url as the argument.

For example:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    music = musicList[position]
    holder.binding.layoutOfTheListItem.setOnClickListener { playVideo(music.videoUrl) }
    // replace layoutOfTheListItem with the button or layout you want the user to click to load the video
}


private fun playVideo(videoId: String) {
    val youTubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView = binding.youtubePlayerView
    lifecycle.addObserver(youTubePlayerView)

    youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(
        object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0f)
            }
        }
    )
}
```